# Передача rvalue параметра в lvalue возвращаемое значение

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, clang, c++20

```
int& foo(int&& x) {
    return x;
}
```

Почему `clang 15.0.0` компилирует этот код без проблем с флагом `c++20` и не компилирует с флагом `c++2b`?

> error: non-const lvalue reference to type 'int' cannot bind to a
> temporary of type 'int'

`gcc 12.2.0` и `msvc 19.33` [компилируют без проблем](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:3,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:3,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:3,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:3),source:%27int%26+foo(int%26%26+x)+%7B%0A++++return+x%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:22.900262467191602,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:conformance,i:(compilers:!((compilerId:clang1500,options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B2b%27),(compilerId:clang1500,options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20%27),(compilerId:g122,options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B2b%27),(compilerId:g122,options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20%27),(compilerId:vcpp_v19_33_x64,options:%27/std:c%2B%2Blatest%27),(compilerId:vcpp_v19_33_x64,options:%27/std:c%2B%2B20%27)),editorid:1,langId:c%2B%2B,libs:!()),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Conformance+Viewer+(Editor+%231)+6/15%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:43.766404199475076,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+clang+15.0.0%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+clang+15.0.0+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1500,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B2b%27,source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+clang+15.0.0+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.33333333333333,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:33.33333333333333,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4). Кто прав?

Comment: Все правы. Много чего можно сейчас, чего нельзя было раньше.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, а не могли бы Вы объяснить чуть подробнее? Я вот не понимаю, как можно инициализировать non-const lvalue reference с помощью rvalue. Если бы там была константная ссылка, все хорошо, мы продлеваем временному объекту жизнь. Но ведь ее нет.

Comment: Судя по моим экспериментам с VC++, временный объект умирает, и имеем ссылку на просто место в памяти, где должен был бы быть объект... Т.е. типичное UB. Почему компилятор не пытается это отлавливать, и кто прав — не скажу, не настолько со стандартом дружу. И вообще это просто догадки на основе экспериментов :)

Comment: @isnullxbh,   int&& x = 10;    int& y = x;;  почему нельзя?...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, эм, так вроде мы другой пример разбираем, нет?) В Вашем примере int&& продлевает жизнь временного объекта, нет никаких проблем. В исходном примере они есть (с моей точки зрения). Если это не так - просьба объяснить.

Comment: @isnullxbh, вы намек не поняли, ладно... при вызове функции выполняется именно это. Если в аргумент передадите rvalue,  все ок, иначе ошибка. И так, компилятор может разрешить это, пока вызов с ожидаемым аргументом. А может подойти строго и не разрешить. Но кто знает что вы задумали?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, в примере с функцией есть нюансы. В Вашем примере int&& продлевает жизнь временному объекту, я именно так выше и написал. Нет никаких проблем с тем, чтобы проинициализировать этим значением non-const lvalue reference. В исходном примере мы возвращаем ссылку на объект, который должен умереть. Получается, мы возвращаем dangling reference. Повторюсь, Ваш пример и исходный - отличаются.

Comment: все, не будем разворачиваться, не то будет  объемное обсуждение....

Comment: Вопрос остается открытым, ответа не прозвучало.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140642/discussion-between-ar-hovsepyan-and-isnullxbh).

Answer (score 1):

Ну вот такой "экспериментальный" код. Когда мы сохраняем именно возвращенную ссылку.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

class Test {
public:
    Test(int x = 0):val_(x){ cout << "Test(" << x << ")\n"; }
    Test(const Test& t):val_(t.val_) { cout << "Test(const Test& " << t.val_ << ")\n"; }
    Test(Test&&t)      :val_(t.val_) { t.val_ = 0; cout << "Test(const Test&& " << t.val_ << ")\n"; }
    Test& operator = (const Test& t)  {
        cout << "Test& operator = (const Test& " << t.val_ <<")\n";
        val_ = t.val_;
        return *this;}
    Test& operator = (Test&& t) {
        cout << "Test& operator = (const Test&&" << t.val_ <<")\n";
        val_ = t.val_; t.val_ = 0;
        return *this;}
    ~Test()           { cout << "~Test(" << val_ <<")\n"; }
    int val() const { return val_; }
private:
    int val_ = 0;
};

Test& foo(Test&& x) {
    return x;
}

int main()
{
    Test& y = foo(5);
    cout << "y.val() = " << y.val() << endl;
}
```

И VC++, и g++ дают одинаковый [результат](https://ideone.com/swPLxt), из которого очевидно, что временный объект уничтожается, и обращение выполняется по ссылке в никуда.

Если написать

```
int main()
{
    Test&& x = 10;
    Test&  y = x;
    cout << "y.val() = " << y.val() << endl;
}
```

то понятно, что пока `x` в области видимости, объект будет жить, и деструктор будет вызван после обращения к `y.val()`.

Comment: Вопрос в том почему это компилируется  современными компиляторами...  
 и почему  ++foo(5) выдаст результат?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Вопрос не в том, почему компилируется, а почему не выдает предупреждения (в конце концов, возврат ссылки на локальную переменную компилируется, но с предупреждениями).

Comment: Harry,   локальная переменная, созданная в теле функции это одно _ в таком случаи она не пройдет компиляцию. А тут  аргумент.  Другое дело, что это  плохо, но языку никак не противоречит. Компилятор может оставить на  совесть программиста, а может поступить иначе.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Не пройдет, говорите? https://ideone.com/5Radf2